# mybatis config problem

Tags: database, config, mybatis

I'm new to MyBatis.

Ive been trying to configure mybatis in a webservice I'm writing but with no luck yet.

What I've done already is,

1. UserInfoMapper interface
2. UserInfoMapper.xml with mapper namespace with my UserInfoMapper interface and a select
3. mybatis-config.xml with typeAlias to use as result type in UserInfoMapper.xml
4. dataSource bean for oracle (I get connected) in datasourceContext.xml
5. org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer bean with basePackage pointing to my UserInfoMapper interface in datasourceContext.xml
6. sqlSessionFactory bean ie. org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean with property for my dataSource and configLocation
7. userInfoMapper bean ie. org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean with property mapperInterface (value="is.simnn.act.web.ngs.persistence.UserInfoMapper") and sqlSessionFactory property (ref="sqlSessionFactory") in datasourceContext.xml
8. then in my applicationContext.xml I have following,

> 

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/wsContext.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/db/datasourceContext.xml" />
```

In my test case I keep getting NullPointerException when I call jaxws:endpoint and it leads me to my UserInfoMapper interface.

Any idea or hints to what might be wrong with my config?

Thanks,
Gunnlaugur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to comment without having more information. Can you post your UserInfoMapper.java interface, your UserInfoMapper.xml and your stack trace, please? Are you certain that the method name in your interface matches the ID of your SELECT in the XML?

Comment: Hi Mark, here is my xml <mapper namespace="is.simnn.act.web.ngs.mappers.UserInfoMapper">

 <select id="getUserInfoBySnb" parameterType="string" resultType="userInfo">
  SELECT
   port.snb,
   port.timestamp,
   port.user_type,
   port.real_exch,
   port.act_exch,
   port.dev_type,
   port.rc
  FROM 
   port
  WHERE 
   port.snb = #{snb}
 </select></mapper>
And this is my interface public interface UserInfoMapper {

 public UserInfo getUserInfoBySnb(String snb);
 public UserInfo getAllUserInfoBySnb(String snb);
 public UserInfo getUserInfoByImsi(String imsi);
}

Comment: Ok, I managed to get rid of the NullPointerException but now I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for is.simnn.act.web.ngs.mappers.UserInfoMapper.getUserInfoBySnb. I'm using mybatis-spring-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT and mybatis-3.0.5-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Is the resultType `userInfo` in your XML a typeAlias? If not, you will need to name your result type class with the full package name: com.your.package.UserInfo. Also you could try adding the annotation `@Param("snb")` to your UserInfoMapper interface, e.g. `public UserInfo getUserInfoBySnb(@Param("snb") String snb)`